# Bandbox issue while typing text on it

Tags: java, hibernate, zk

Typing on bandbox search,sometimes cursor deletes previous letter and validates search option and executes hibernate query.Can any one tell me the reason for this??and how to avoid this problem.

I am using Hibernate,PostgreSQL and Zk framework.

```
Zul:

<bandbox id="mrnSearch2" sclass="mybandbox" tooltiptext="${c:l('bandbox_NameSearch.tooltiptext')}" mold="rounded" >
                            <attribute name="onSelect">
                 if(self.getSelectedIndex() != 1 ){
                    mrnSearch2.value= self.selectedItem.label;
                 }; 
                 mrnSearch2.closeDropdown();
                </attribute>
                </bandbox>
```

In Controller Class i am listing items with help of below method,

```
CommonBandpopup.generateMrnBandbox(mrnSearch);
```

(In  service implementation part i am having above method. )

```
public void onSelectedResult$mrnSearch() {
    Patient patient = (Patient) mrnSearch.getAttribute("selectedItem");
    if (patient != null) {
        mrnSearch.setValue(patient.getPatientMrn());
        textbox_PatientName.setValue(patient.getFullName());
    }

}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more details.

Comment: public void onSelectedResult$mrnSearch2() {
  Patient patient = (Patient) mrnSearch2.getAttribute("selectedItem");
  if (patient != null) {
   mrnSearch2.setValue(patient.getPatientMrn());
  }
 }

Comment: That one is my searching functionality for bandbox.I am just getting selected value by object and based on that searching values in bandbox..

Comment: The problem is not in searching part.Problem is while typing text on bandbox that time only i am getting that issue..It doesnt show any error or exception in backend.

Comment: Pattu, please edit your question with the zul page and the controller.

Comment: sounds like an issue that the search is busy and you set a char. When the search finished you set back the searched value in the textbox.  That's also why you don't have an error because there is none (had similar issue once)

Comment: Thanks chillworld for ur valuable comment.